Is this the difference between a voucher and a gift card?
A voucher features a specific service or product that you can get for free at a specific place whereas a gift certificate features a specific monetary value for which you can buy products or services at a given place/given places.
I know that a voucher is usually given by a business as compensation and that a gift card is a gift that one person gives to another.

Both terms have multiple meanings, which overlap. So you can't expect to find a single difference that separates them. But you can certainly get something called a voucher with a specific monetary value. (Vouchers used to typically be thinner paper than cards, but these days both can be digital.)

Can you please explain the differences? The link isn't helpful.

Native Anglophones wouldn't normally care about differences between gift certificate, gift voucher, store credit, voucher, coupon... But if it matters to you, and the can't find what you want to know from English dictionaries, take it to English Language Learners
